# How do I get certain PDF form fields to insert in body of email using javascript

Tags: javascript, email, kofax

Good Afternoon,

I'm hoping someone can assist.  I am not an experienced coder but through googling this is what I have come up with.  I have a form with account information that I would like to run a java script to generate a "Welcome Letter" to new users with the information on the form that I have filled out.  I created the body of the message but have no idea how to insert from the form.  I would also like the fields that I am pulling the data from to be bold text.  The form fields are titled

First

Username

Email Address

Ext

Extension

Time#

`app.mailmsg(false,\\\I would like to pull the user's email address from the form for this section as well\\\,"","","Welcome Aboard!", "Good Morning" \\\Use form field First\\\"Your username:"  \\\Pull username\\\`

The body and insert of form fields continues throughout. I apologize if this coding is sloppy I'm truly a novice.  I am using Kofax Power PDF.  Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet of the existing code that you have?

Comment: 'app.mailMsg(false, "", "", "", "Welcome Aboard!", "Good Morning \n \n" + "Here is your account information for your records: \n \n" + "Your username: \n" + "Your temporary password: \\This isn’t on the form but is predefined\\ \n" + "Your email address: \n \n" + "Your phone extension in house: \n" + "Your direct line: \n" + "Your timekeeper number: \n \n" + "Welcome aboard again!" );'

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. Could you add all of the code in your file or the vast majority of it to your existing question so we can help you out?

Comment: That's it.  I click the action button in Kofax Power PDF and it generates the email with the information I have above.  I've tried to use this site in the past and just got blasted for not understanding how this works.  If I could upload my file PDF file to show you I would but I don't see that option.  I appreciate your swift response and willingness to help.

Comment: Ya people on here are not always the most friendly, sorry about that. I have not used `Kofax Power PDF` before. Is that where `app.mailMsg(false, "", "", "", "Welcome Aboard!", "Good Morning \n \n Here is your account information for your records: \n \n Your username: \n Your temporary password: \\This isn’t on the form but is predefined\\ \n Your email address: \n \n Your phone extension in house: \n Your direct line: \n Your timekeeper number: \n \n Welcome aboard again!");` is defined or do you have a javascript file (or similar) somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is defined in Kofax.  I have another script that I am pulling the data to send the PDF pulling the data into the subject line of the email but I don't know how to do it for the body while also having text in there.  'var customSubject = this.getField("Office").value + "- " + this.getField("Title").value + "- " + this.getField("Date").value + "  " + this.getField("First").value + " " + this.getField("Last").value;
var mailtoUrl = "mailto:csupport@rawle.com?subject=New Hire " + customSubject;
this.submitForm({ 
 cURL: mailtoUrl, cSubmitAs: "PDF" });'